# What is the default font for Grub in Ubuntu and Fedora?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub, fonts

I was wondering what the name of the font is for the grub set by default after installation in Ubuntu and Fedora (they are different ones). Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.. Some people are asking about this..
Ubuntu is using font that's called "Ubuntu Font Family"
Sounds Familiar?
Ubuntu Font Family is an OpenType TTF based font, designed to be a modern humanist-style font by London-based type foundry Dalton Maag, with funding by Canonical Ltd. The font was under development for nearly nine months, with only a limited initial release through a beta program, until September 2010. It was then that it became the new default font of the Ubuntu operating system in Ubuntu 10.10.

Reference : [Wikipedia's page about Ubuntu font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28typeface%29)

Comment: I was under the impression that grub2 just used the console font, but as I see that screen rarely I'd never looked closer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we're speaking about the same thing here. GRUB is separate from Ubuntu and doesn't share the same font. By looking at your GRUB config file, usually at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, you should see a line that loads a font like this: `if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then`...